# How to retrieve String from NSDictionary in objective C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays

I am trying to retrieve the value for a key in a NSDictionary.  The dictionary has been initialised with key value pairs both of type string.  The trouble is, I cannot seem to retrieve the value with I call objectForKey or valueForKey.

I am able to iterate over the dictionary and print both keys and values.

Can someone point out where im going wrong? Here is my code...

```
//Set up dictionary with options
keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"red", @"blue", nil];
values = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1.7", @"2.8", nil];

conversionOptions = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:values 
                                                forKey:keys];
```

Then this is called on the select row in a picker

```
NSLog(@"... %@", [keys objectAtIndex:row]);       //prints out the key
NSString *theString = [keys objectAtIndex:row];   //save it as a string
NSLog(@"The string is... %@", theString);         //print it out to make sure im not going crazy

NSLog(@"the value is : %@",[conversionOptions objectForKey:theString]); // I just get NULL here
//NSLog(@"the value is : %@",[conversionOptions valueForKey:theString]); // This doesn't work either, I just get NULL
```

Comment: You should check your `theString` individually in an `NSLog` before you get the object for that key in order to see if it's actually setting it to the `[keys objectAtIndex:row]`. Perhaps the `row` is not initialized or not returning the desired result and therefore the key is `nil` or `null`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're creating a dictionary with an array as the only key and an array for its value! You want the `dictionaryWithObjects:forKeys:` (plural) factory, not `dictionaryWithObject:forKey:` (singular) so that each element of the keys array will be used as a distinct key for the respective element of the values array.

I find the `dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:` factory to be more useful most of the time, e.g.:

```
conversionOptions = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"1.7", @"red", @"2.8", @"blue", nil];
```

Comment: Yes this worked! I can't believe I didn't see that, thanks :)

Answer (score 8):

This is how you retrieve a string from a dictionary object

`NSString * string = [dictionary objectForKey:@"stringKey"];`

Answer (score 2):

Use `objectForKey:` not `valueForKey:`.

---

Make sure `conversionOptions` is non-nil when you call `objectForKey:` (which is the right method).

And, yeah, derp -- I missed that the wrong factory method was used.  You could do dictionaryWithObjects:andKeys: or do what pmjordan said said.

**You absolutely must use `objectForKey:`, though.**   `valueForKey:` is specific to KVC.

Comment: That doesn't work either, I will update the question to reflect this. Thanks